# Intellisense not working with PTVS(python 3.3)

Tags: visual-studio-2010, python-3.x, intellisense, ptvs

I have both IronPython 2.7 and Python 3.3 installed. Intellisense works perfectly when I use IronPython and other languages but as soon as I switch to Python ,it stops working with a message -"*Intellisense database is currently not up to date and completions may be missing*".Refreshing the databases in Python Environments has no effect and shows "*Completion DB needs refresh*" whereas it says "*Completion DB is up to date*" in IronPython.
Tried

- uninstalling PTVS,Python
- deleting the leftover files in "*..\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft*"

but had no effect. It does work while using python interactive.
How can I get it to work in the editing area?
PTVS version 2.0.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any packages installed for Python 3.3? Or is it direct from python.org? It is possible that some packages will break the completion DB, so if this is the case, I'd encourage you to visit [our forums](http://pytools.codeplex.com/discussions) and post a list there.

Alternatively, did PTVS detect Python automatically or did you add it as a Custom Environment? There are some ways to misconfigure environments that will break the completion DB but not show any other errors.

If you look under Tools->Python Tools->Diagnostic Info you will find the relevant logs. If you don't want to search these yourself, again, I'd encourage you to visit [our forums](http://pytools.codeplex.com/discussions) and post it there.

Comment: I have the ActivePython Community edition from [link](http://www.activestate.com/activepython/downloads).PTVS detected Python automatically.If this doesn't help please let me know,I'll try the forums.Thanks.

Comment: They've released newer versions that we haven't tested, so it's possible that they've found a bug in our code somewhere. I'll give it a go - meanwhile you could try [PTVS 2.1 Alpha](https://pytools.codeplex.com/releases/view/117511) (or our [dev build](https://pytools.codeplex.com/releases/view/113962), which is *nearly* beta) to see if we've already fixed it.